# Google is now indexing individual answers?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've noticed a very annoying trend where individual answers are being indexed by Google. Often these are not even the accepted answer but for whatever reason it's what gets picked up.

Is this a recent change in SO's indexing policy? A profile setting to always go to the question would be awesome.

[image]

Comment: I would think that it would be helpful to have the page scroll to the answer that contained the content that the search ended up matching.

Comment: Why is this annoying? Otherwise if there is an answer that matches my specific search terms, I have to scroll to find it, or perform another search within the page. If I search my Inbox for messages containing some search phrase, I'd rather it point me to the individual message that actually contains it, not the first message in the thread.

Comment: @AaronBertrand because seeing the answer out of context with the question usually isn't helpful. Often it's a slightly different question or I need to translate the answer a bit for it to fit my needs. Replies in your Inbox usually contain that context already and often aren't question-and-answer format. Just differences in how we process information I suppose.

Comment: @TobyJ if the SO question is "How do I fizz the buzz?" and I am trying to fizz the buzz using a specific tool, then I would rather go to the answer that happens to deal with that tool, rather than land at the top of the page. Anyway, it appears that this was a mistake, so you still get to have it your way once Google catches up.